# How can I add a symbol to a click.prompt user input?

Tags: python, click, user-input, prompt

So I want to make is so it has "$" before the input.

`original_price = click.prompt('Please enter the flight fare' ,type=int)`

So that this code shows as:

`Please enter the flight fare: $1`

However click puts ":" after the question so if I were to do

`original_price = click.prompt('Please enter the flight fare: $' ,type=int)`

It prints as

`Please enter the flight fare: $:`

Please help!

Comment: ```original_price = click.prompt('Please enter the flight fare: $' ,type=int)```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but here it goes:

```
original_price = click.prompt('Please enter the flight fare: $', type = int, prompt_suffix='')
```

As you can see in the [click.prompt() documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.prompt), there is the `prompt_suffix` parameter that defines the suffix of the prompt. The default value is `:`, as you noticed, so we just change to `''` that is an empty string. Always search for the documentation on Google if you have trouble using some method/function.

Another way would be using `$` as suffix:

```
original_price = click.prompt('Please enter the flight fare: ', type = int, prompt_suffix='$')
```